# CentOS Crontab - Extract particular file name

Tags: cron, 7z

Let's assume that I have a file with extension of .7z and I have a crontab that extracts this file. But the name is unknown, only the extension is known, is it possible to extract it from crontab?

Here is my crontab:

```
2 * * * * root cd /var/path_to_directory && 7za x ".7z*"-p'abc'
```

This however, does not work and results in: `there is no such archive`

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `cd /var/path_to_directory && 7z x "*.7z" -p'abc'`

Comment: Why did you put `*` after .7z extension? If you don't know the name, you have to put asterisk before. @heemayl gave you correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You ran the command `7za` with the two arguments `x` and `.7z*-pabc`. The file name and the `-p` option need to be separate arguments. Furthermore `.7z*` would match file names that *begin* with `.7z`, not file names that end with `.7z`.

```
7za x "*.7z" -p'abc'
```

Note that the fact that you can pass `*.7z` to the `7za` command (or more precisely that it does something meaningful with that argument) is specific to that command. Normally, wildcards are expanded by the shell, so if you wanted to extract a file from `foo.7z` which is the only `.7z` file in the current directory, you'd need to write `7za x *.7z -p'abc'`; the shell would pass the arguments `x`, `foo.7z` and `-p'abc'` to the `7za` command. That would work; but `7za` does its own wildcard processing (because it's a port of DOS software, and DOS didn't do wildcard processing), so you can also write `7za x "*.7z" -p'abc'`, where the second argument to `7za` is the string `*.7z`.